# Run code after after the page is rendered to the user (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, high-load

I'm looking for a way to run some slow code after after the page is rendered to the user. Concretely, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
get '/fast-action' do
  compute_after_render { put some slow code here }
  'request successful'
end
```

I thought about inserting the information about the computation into the database.
And then running something like rufus scheduler that would be checking if there is something to compute once a minute. 
But I wouldn't want the user to wait for the database to complete the insertion.
**Is there any way to make Sinatra run some code after after the page is rendered to the user?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one quick and easy way is to start a new thread:

```
get '/fast-action' do
  body 'request successful'
  Thread.new{ slow code }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [streaming responses](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Streaming%20Responses):

```
get '/fast-action' do
  stream do |out|
    out << 'request successful'
    put some slow code here
    out << " "
  end
end
```

Be aware though, that server thread **will be blocked** for the duration of that request (and of course execution of slow code).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into side jobs.  I like to use the [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) gem for this.  It uses Redis to store jobs that need to be run and checks it every once and a while.  It's totally configurable and all that.  I highly recommend it if you're running jobs that can be done later, such as sending email, processing images and such, and running long processes.